# How to get child and convert into double in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

bea3d

- list

  - 50:EA:EC:0C:50:DF

    - ID: " L084"
    - brand: "BE"
    - locate

      - lat: "130.7273835"
      - long: "10.776167"
    - name
    - shade
  - 74:FA:FF:80:4D:E1

    - ID: " GS58"
    - brand: "TTA"
    - locate

      - lat: "130.7273835"
      - long: "10.776167"
  - 23:EA:FC:00:67:FD

    - ID: " P09A"
    - brand: "EE"
    - locate

      - lat: "130.7273835"
      - long: "10.776167"

How to get only lat and long value in Kotlin from every key in my list?
And how to convert these values to Double for use marker in the map?

Comment: where is the list, you should provided mimal reproducable question.

Comment: Please post what have you done so far ?

Comment: Sorry Sir. I want to get value lat and long from 50:EA:EC:0C:50:DF, 74:FA:FF:80:4D:E1 and 23:EA:FC:00:67:FD. I have tried other posts that have previously been answered.

Comment: is this is the JSON response coming from the API or something else.

Comment: I don't understand what you are meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "bea3d" is the root reference of your Firebase Realtime Database, to get the value of "lat" and "long" that exist underneath each node, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val listRef = rootRef.child("list")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val lat = ds.child("locate/lat").getValue(String::class.java).toDouble()
            val long = ds.child("locate/long").getValue(String::class.java).toDouble()
            Log.d("TAG", lat + "," + long)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
listRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Ther result in the logcat will be:

```
130.7273835, 10.776167
130.7273835, 10.776167
130.7273835, 10.776167
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I try to use this code but it has a error 
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
Then I try to change .toDouble() => ?.toDouble() or  !!.toDouble()
And the Logcat doesn't showing

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Please see my updated answer. It should have been `.child("locate/lat")` and **not** `.child("location/lat")`. Give it again a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much sir.